# Date as xlim in R

Tags: r

I was trying to draw some lines in the same plot. The x factor is determined by a date and the y factor by a number. I initially load the data, store it in a list and save the min and max values for the date:

```
stocks <- list()
stocks.min <- 0
stocks.max <- 0
stocks.min.date <- NULL
stocks.max.date <- NULL
for (name in names(files))
{
  stocks[[name]] <- read.csv(files[[name]], sep=";")

  # Convert to date in R
  stocks[[name]]$Date <- as.Date(stocks[[name]]$Date, "%d/%m/%Y")

  # Sets max value for ylim in the plotting
  if (stocks.max < max(stocks[[name]]$Close))
  {
    stocks.max <- max(stocks[[name]]$Close)
  }

  # Sets the date value for the xlim in the plot
  if (is.null(stocks.min.date) || min(stocks[[name]]$Date) < stocks.min.date)
  {
    stocks.min.date <- min(stocks[[name]]$Date)
  }
  if (is.null(stocks.max.date) || max(stocks[[name]]$Date) > stocks.max.date)
  {
    stocks.max.date <- max(stocks[[name]]$Date)
  }
}
```

After that I create an empty plot using the values from above:

```
plot(0, xlab="Time", ylab="Closing Prices", main="Stock Values", 
 xlim=c(stocks.min.date, stocks.max.date), ylim=c(stocks.min, stocks.max))
```

And then I add the lines with the data:

```
for (name in names(stocks))
{
  lines(x=stocks[[name]]$Date, y=stocks[[name]]$Close, col=colors[[name]], type="l", 
    lwd=2)
}
```

When the graph is plotted, the data is correctly displayed, but it shows the date as numbers instead of dates in the x axis as seen in the image below:

[image]

How can I correct this issue?

Comment: `stocks[[name]]$Date <- as.Date(stocks[[name]]$Date)` before the plotting command, and then your plot labeling should work as expected.

Comment: I already do this when I'm loading the data in the first for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly suggest using a normalized series to plot  the stocks data you have. `quantmod` helps a lot here. It solves two purposes -

1. Get the x-axis labels as dates.
2. Normalize series so that you can view any number of series without worrying about the orders of their absolute values (~67 for INR, ~1120 for KRW, so on...)

This is what I generally use for my purposes.

```
library(quantmod)

tickers <- c('GOOG', 'MSFT', 'AAPL', 'AMZN')
getSymbols(tickers, src = 'yahoo', from = '2015-01-01')

normalise <- function(x) x/as.numeric(x)[1] - 1

chart_theme <- chart_theme()
chart_theme$col$line.col <- "red"

chart_Series(normalise(Cl(GOOG)), theme = chart_theme)
add_TA(normalise(Cl(MSFT)), on = 1, col = "black", lty = 1)
add_TA(normalise(Cl(AMZN)), on = 1, col = "blue", lty =1)
add_TA(normalise(Cl(AAPL)), on = 1, col = "darkgreen", lty =2)
```

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: I could not make this work, nor reuse this in a way that the time was shown correctly =/

Comment: Were you able to replicate the code? What errors does it show when you try to replicate the above or when you modify the code for your needs?